# Approximating sin using the Taylor series

Tags: python, trigonometry, taylor-series

I'm trying to calculate `sin(x)` using Taylor series without using factorials.

```
import math, time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

def sin3(x, i=30):
    x %= 2 * math.pi
    n = 0
    dn = x**2 / 2
    for c in range(4, 2 * i + 4, 2):
        n += dn
        dn *= -x**2 / ((c + 1) * (c + 2))
    return x - n

def draw_graph(start = -800, end = 800):
    y = [sin3(i/100) for i in range(start, end)]
    x = [i/100 for i in range(start, end)]

    y2 = [math.sin(i/100) for i in range(start, end)]
    x2 = [i/100 for i in range(start, end)]

    plot.fill_between(x, y, facecolor="none", edgecolor="red", lw=0.7)
    plot.fill_between(x2, y2, facecolor="none", edgecolor="blue", lw=0.7)
    plot.show()
```

When you run the `draw_graph` function it uses matplotlib to draw a graph, the redline is the output from my `sin3` function, and the blue line is the correct output from the `math.sin` method.

[image]

As you can see the curve is not quite right, it's not high or low enough (seems to peak at 0.5), and also has strange behavior where it generates a small peak around 0.25 then drops down again. How can I adjust my function to match the correct output of math.sin?

Comment: Now's a good time to learn [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [to use a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)  
Step through your code and observe what each line of code does. 
Identify where your program differs from your expectations by comparing these intermediate results with expected results. 
Work backwards from there to narrow down the cause of the problem. 
Then ask a _specific_ question if you are still confused by your code's behavior. It's not okay to dump your code and expect other people to debug it for you.

Comment: The question is specific, im asking how to generate sin using Taylor series without using factorials. Hows that not a specific question?

Comment: "How can I do this task" or "fix my code" are not specific questions. What debugging have you done? Have you written out the Taylor series expansion and compared the terms generated by your `sin3()`? Have you tried to identify which term / which line of code causes the problem?

Comment: I've tried changing the n variable, as well as where the loops starts and ends multiple times over the last few hours, `range(4, 2 * i + 4, 2)` seems to have generated the most accurate looking result so far, but it still of from the correct result.

Comment: @harold what should I change then to use odd powers

Comment: If this is a question on how the mathematics should be done, not how the implement, you might be better off asking on math.stackexchange or similar

Comment: the function is a modified version of the cos function, sin and cos are very similar with cos using even powers and sin using odd powers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong equation for sin(x), and you also have a messed up loop invariant.

The formula for `sin(x)` is `x/1! - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7!...`, so I really don't know why you're initializing `dn` to something involving `x^2`.

You also want to ask yourself:  What is my loop invariant?  What is the value of `dn` when I reach the start of my loop.  It is clear from the way you update dn that you expect it to be something involving `x^i / i!`.  Yet on the very first iteration of the loop, `i=4`, yet `dn` involves `x^2`.

Here is what you meant to write:

```
def sin3(x, i=30):
    x %= 2 * math.pi
    n = 0
    dn = x
    for c in range(1, 2 * i + 4, 2):
        n += dn
        dn *= -x**2 / ((c + 1) * (c + 2))
    return n
```

Comment: As a minor nit.  For better accuracy, you want `-π ≤ x ≤ π` rather than `0 ≤ x ≤ 2π`.  So the first line could be `x = (x + math.pi) % (2 * math.pi) - math.pi`.